# How can I use Custom Layout for Specific Pages of the Vuepress?

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I'm trying to use my own Custome Layout of the vuepress as following steps:

1. Start from [Homepage style](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#homepage) in the VuePress Document, this is working well.

[image]

2. Make the **T4V4Home.vue** for special layout as coping from Home.vue on the theme/components folder which is ejected, and add a `<h1> This is T4V4Home !</h1>` in these `<template>` for an indication as follows.

```
<template>
  <main
    class="home"
    aria-labelledby="main-title"
  >

    <h1> This is T4V4Home !</h1>

    <header class="hero">
```

3. Add **layout: T4V4Home** as follow as the step of [Custom Layout for Specific Pages](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#custom-layout-for-specific-pages) in the VuePress Document, in the Readme.md, but `<h1> This is T4V4Home !</h1>` **doesn't appear**, seems old "Home.vue" is **still used**.

```
---
layout: T4V4Home
home: true
#heroImage: /ueda4googleplaystore.png
heroText: Hero Title
tagline: Hero subtitle
actionText: Get Started →
actionLink: /guide/
features:
```

[image]

4. So, remove **home: true** as follows, but the standard **Page** layout is used unexpectedly as follows.

```
---
layout: T4V4Home
#home: true
#heroImage: /ueda4googleplaystore.png
heroText: Hero Title
tagline: Hero subtitle
actionText: Get Started →
actionLink: /guide/
features:
```

[image]

How can I activate and use my Custom Layout **T4V4Home**? Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where are you putting your Custom Layout component?

The Custom Layout is working fine for me with VuePress `1.3.0`.

1. Create a `SpecialLayout.vue` files at `.vuepress/components/SpecialLayout.vue`, and copy everything in the [Home.vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/master/packages/%40vuepress/theme-default/components/Home.vue) into it. And then add a line `<h1>This is a test</h1>` into it.
2. Change the Frontmatter in the `README.md` accordingly.

```
---
layout: SpecialLayout
heroImage: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/hero.png
heroText: test
tagline: 
actionText: Quick Start →
actionLink: /guide/
features:
- title: Feature 1 Title
  details: Feature 1 Description
- title: Feature 2 Title
  details: Feature 2 Description
- title: Feature 3 Title
  details: Feature 3 Description
footer: Made by  with ❤️
---
```

And I successfully get the new HomePage

[image]

However, I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, because as you can see in the screenshot above, you'll lose the `NavBar` at the top of the page because of Custom Layout.

If you want to preserve the `NavBar`, I suggest you try out [Theme Inheritance](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/inheritance.html).

1. Put your customized homepage component at `.vuepress/theme/components/Home.vue`. Yes, it needs to be named as `Home.vue` to replace the one in the default theme.
2. Create a `index.js` file at `.vuepress/theme/index.js` with content

```js
module.exports = {
  extend: '@vuepress/theme-default'
}
```

And don't forget to change the `README.md` back to normal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Sun! I had putted to **.vuepress/theme/components**. It must be root cause ^^; I've moved it to **.vuepress/components** as your suggestion and I've succeeded to show it. I really appreciate your help!