# How can I use markdown in the Homepage layout of the VuePress?

Tags: vuepress

In the **features** tag on the [homepage layout](https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#homepage) of the Vuepress, any markdown notation can't be used due to get the error.
So, I'd like to make my custom layout which is extended from the default homepage layout and to get possible to use markdown.

Is this possible? Any suggestion is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [@Sun Haoran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9478849/sun-haoran)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896744/9831274), but want to note a good way to add content/html is using a component.

We created a front page component called HomeFeatures.vue. ([see the repo](https://github.com/zumasys/docs/blob/master/site/.vuepress/components/HomeFeatures.vue)) Also, we pretty much just copied this straight from [vuepress](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/master/packages/%40vuepress/theme-default/components/Home.vue).

```js
<template>
  <div class="features">
    <div class="feature">
      <h2>AccuTerm</h2>
      <p>
        <a href="/accuterm/getting-started/">Getting Started</a><br />
        <a href="/accuterm/license-activation/">Licensing</a><br />
        <a href="/accuterm/desktop/">Desktop</a><br />
        <a href="/accuterm/web/">Web</a><br />
        <a href="/accuterm/mobile/">Mobile</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
      <h2>jBASE</h2>
      <p><a href="/jbase/">All Docs</a><br /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
      <h2>OpenQM</h2>
      <p>Main (Coming Soon!)<br /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
      <h2>MV Dashboard</h2>
      <p>
        <a href="/mv-dashboard/introduction/">Introduction</a><br />
        <a href="/mv-dashboard/installation-guide/">Installation Guide</a><br />
        <a href="/mv-dashboard/programmers-guide/">Programmers Guide</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
      <h2>MV Connect</h2>
      <p>
        <a href="/mv-connect/">Overview</a><br />
        <a href="/mv-connect/get-started/">Getting Started</a><br />
        <a href="/mv-connect/api/">API</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
      <h2>Customer Portal</h2>
      <p>
        <a href="/customer-portal/">All Docs</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Features'
};
</script>
```

And just included it like so: ([see the repo](https://github.com/zumasys/docs/blob/master/site/README.md))

```
---
home: true
heroImage: /assets/img/logo-grey.png
heroText: Product Documentation
tagline: Welcome to the future
footer: MIT Licensed | Copyright © 2019-present Company Name
---

<HomeFeatures />
```

Our docs live [here](https://docs.zumasys.com/) if you'd like to see it in action.

Comment: Hi, Ryan! Nice idea, I like this approach!
Thank you for your great suggestion and for sharing your suggestive site!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can't without going through a lot of trouble. The default theme's homepage is using YAML front matter to pass on user config texts, which will not be parsed as markdown.

Personally, I suggest you try to use HTML directly with a customized layout. To use a customized layout for the homepage, check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60220684/9478849), and to use HTML see the relavent issue in VuePress [#2186](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/2186)